# Complex pivot query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a table that looks like this in SQL Server:

| Status | 1233SDD | 1234SDD | 1235SDD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Description | Points | Points | Points |
| Source | Website | Website | Website |
| Frequency | 15 days | 15 days | 10 days |
| Country | Australia | Canada | Albania |
| January2021 | 80 | 80 | 50 |
| February2021 | 80 | 60 | 50 |
| March2021 | 80 | 40 | 50 |
| April2021 | 20 | 40 | 50 |
| June2021 | 10 | 40 | 50 |

I pivot it and get a result that will look similar to this:

| Status | Description | Source | Frequency | Country | Month/Year | Points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1233SDD | Points | Website | 15 days | Australia | January2021 | 80 |
| 1233SDD | Points | Website | 15 days | Australia | February2021 | 80 |
| 1233SDD | Points | Website | 15 days | Australia | March2021 | 80 |
| 1233SDD | Points | Website | 15 days | Australia | April2021 | 20 |
| 1233SDD | Points | Website | 15 days | Australia | June2021 | 10 |
| 1234SDD | Points | Website | 15 days | Canada | January2021 | 80 |
| 1234SDD | Points | Website | 15 days | Canada | February2021 | 60 |

I don't even know where to start considering the data it's all over the place, any ideas?

Edit: The months cannot be a column because the table will be updated with new rows frequently, sometimes with two different types of data for the same month. The month column dates also back from year 2012 to current year 2022, so that's why it cannot be a column in itself.

The data comes in files as the table 1 and needs to be transformed as table 2 in SQL.

Comment: Blargh, I would suggest, in truth, that you fix this in the first place; you are breaking multiple fundamental normalisation rules in the above. There's not even any details on what rows related to what; for example how do you know `Description` and `Source` should be a column, but `January` or row?

Comment: why not scrap the table 1, and just use the design in table 2 (it's still not great, but a bit better)

Comment: *"The months cannot be a column because the table will be updated with new rows frequently, sometimes with two different types of data for the same month."* Doesn't explain anything. That it can't be doesn't explain *how* you, or more importantly, he *data engine* knows.

Comment: Unpivot and pivot the rows excluding the monthly ones, unpivot the months and join the two..